# Виджет для отображения подрубрик или постов

Tags: wordpress

как сделать логику для отображения рубрик в сайдбаре:
Если у рубрики есть подрубрики отображать подрубрики
если нет, отображать ссылки к постам в текущей рубрике

Если пользователь находиться в рубрике имеющей подрубрики отображать так:

```
Родительская рубрика:
   Подрубрика
   Подрубрика
   Подрубрика
```

Если пользователь находиться в рубрике не имеющей подрубрики отображать так:

```
Подрубрика
   Ссылка Поста
   Ссылка Поста
   Ссылка Поста
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это должно выглядить как-то так:

```
$current_term = get_queried_object();
$children     = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy'   => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent'     => $term->term_id
] );
if ( ! empty( $children ) ) {
    // show children
} else {
    $neighbors = get_terms( [
        'taxonomy'   => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'parent'     => $term->parent
    ] );
    // show heighbors
}
```